# Facebook ignores og:image when sharing url?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, share, status

I created a website - http://mati.ravpage.co.il/check4
The website contains one og:image tag and is linted properly.

However, when I want to share this link (by placing it inside a newly created status): it shows two possible thumbnail, the default being different then the one declared in og:image.
You can see this in the following screenshot: [screen shot](http://images.ravpages.co.il/xsite_resources/user_content/a2fa09f7e331c73ec8ba3b64b846d7dd/images/d3ee6664db5e4078207911f8e6cdb06b.png)

- The picture shown as default thumbnail is one contained within the page.

I'm using Chrome and am pretty sure it was different a few weeks ago - back then only the og:image thumbnail was shown.

Am I doing something wrong here, are the og:... tags improper or is it a new Facebook behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Mati Skiba

Answer (score 6):

This page will tell you what's wrong, if anything: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. For me, the image was too small (200 x 200 min).

Comment: This page doesn't help. I keep using it and it tells me I have the correct og image but then uses the logo anyway.

Comment: I came across this too. View source shows the correct image in the og:image, but then facebook debugger is choosing a different image, that doesn't even have og:image tag. Weird

Comment: I have a 200x200 image in the og:image tag but the debugger chooses another image from the page and places it in the og:image discarding the original value, saying that the original image is too small (which is false)

Comment: We had this problem and it turned out we had header content - including og tags - outside of <head>. This broke the FB parser. The suggestion below to use the HTML validator was super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It might be good to check the html not only in Facebook linter, but in HTML validation tools as well. One of them is the one created by [W3C](http://validator.w3.org/).

For the mentioned site it points out a [few mistakes](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmati.ravpage.co.il%2Fcheck4&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), and as the <meta> tags have issues as well, this might be the reason for Facebook parsing the whole page for pictures.

For example:

```
<meta xmlns="" property="og:url" content="http://mati.ravpage.co.il/check4">
```

should be (pay attention to the slash at the end)

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mati.ravpage.co.il/check4" />
```

Comment: This linter was gold, I spelled  `property` `proprety`